# Combine two forms into one submit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

So I have two forms on one page

```
<form name="form1" method="post" id="form1">
...
<button id="next">NEXT</button>
</form>

<form name="form2" method="post" id="form2" action="doSomething.php">
...
<button id="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Both forms are validated using the jQuery validate plugin. When form1 is completed and validated then form2 is displayed.

What I'd like to happen is when the user clicks submit on form2 it should take the data from form1, combine it with form2 and do a single POST submit to doSomething.php. Almost as if form1 and form2 were really just one big form. **NOTE: I'm not using AJAX.**

I could combine them into one form, but because of my needs for jQuery Validation it's not feasible. 
Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like you should pick a different validation plug in.

Comment: really? It's pretty good other than that one feature. I can assign custom error classes. I need different error classes for the different forms. form1 is just input fields, name, age, dob, etc. Form2 is all radiobox questions.

Comment: Why don't you just make one form and then break it up with a `<div>` or a `<span>`?

Comment: @David I did have that initially. However, I needed to apply different error classes to the 2 types. With the jQuery Validation plugin you can only validate one form at a time. So I needed to split them apart. eg. Form1 needs to have an error class of "tooltip" and form2 needs to have an error class of "redBorder"

Comment: So create rules in the stylesheet that override what you need. `.part1 .whateverthelibrary adds {  /* yep */ } .part2 .whateverthelibrary adds {  /* yep */ }`

Comment: Well that's part of the issue. But since the 2nd part of the form is "hidden" I don't know if the Validation plugin will attempt to validate the hidden fields too... I'll try out your suggestion, but I'd really like to know how to combine the two forms into one POST submit.